# Can I submit a form with google's recaptcha in it from my app?

Tags: http, request, authorization, captcha, recaptcha

I'm writing an app which involves letting users to share comments on a website, which has a comment form with Google's reCAPTCHA embeded. I would like to load this page via HTTP and display CAPTCHA within my app, so that user can post comments from my app. Is it easy to implement or should I rather try other solution?

EDIT:
I've red reCAPTCHA developer guide. If I would like to embed captcha inside my form, I'd need to insert div element with a proper class, and make a ajax request in order to render captcha. This call would insert an iframe into a given div. What I need is to know how to access that iframe's content without using AJAX.

Comment: It is quite easy to implement. Just follow the instructions on the developer guide.

Comment: @panda.o24 I cannot found what I need in Developer Guide. I've appended more info to my question, please take a look, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we are not supposed to do that kind of tricks with reCAPTCHA.
There is no support for that in API. It seems that it was part of Google's design to prevent that kind of usage.

The only walkaround I could come up with is to implement a WebView widget with JavaScript support, get website via http, and load it into this webview, centering this view around the form we want to post.

It seems like a lot of work though, thus I'm going to simply skip this, if someone successfuly manages to figure it out I'd appreciate a hint :)